Creating xarray DataArray for 1d elevation track
I am new to using xarray and I thought a good intro would be loading a geoJSON track into a DataArray. My parsed data is a 2103 x 4 array made up of 2,103 waypoints from a GPS track:



_
item
units




0
longitude
deg


1
latitude
deg


2
elevation
meters above sea level


3
timestamp
unix millisecond



Here is how I have tried to put this into a DataArray:
track = xa.DataArray(
    data=data[:,2],
    dims=['x'],
    coords=dict(
        lon=(['x'], data[:,0]),
        lat=(['x'], data[:,1]),
        time=(['x'], data[:,3]),
    ),
    attrs=dict(
        description='GPS track',
        units='Meters above sea level'
    ),
    name='sample_track'

I want to use more of xarray's functionality. Some questions I have that the API reference isn't clear about:

reference_time: How do I employ a reference time for unix milliseconds, i.e. milliseconds past 1970?

Should I be converting to a different time format?
Some code examples with time series have unit strings e.g. 'days since 1990-1-1 0:0:0', does that come into play here?


Am I using dims correctly?
Am I using units correctly in attrs?
I actually have 9 individual tracks, right now I'm using a list of 9 DataArrays. Is there a way in xarray that I can neatly store them together?
Is there any way to specify data units and physical units? E.g. the elevation is saved as integers, but I want to use float32 for the lon/lat.
Later on I want to plot a track using the lon/lat values. I need [(lon, lat), ..., (lon, lat)] format. Is there a better way to get that than list(zip(track.lon.values, track.lat.values))?

Thanks!
